# json to xml in java using json.org jar giving &quot

Tags: xml, json, org.json

org.jar to convert json to xml but while converting its giving output including &quot.

Json :
{"Organization":{"Company":[{"ComapnyAddress":"Address1","CompanyName":"ABCD"},{"ComapnyAddress":"Address2","CompanyName":"PQRS"}]}}

XML:

"{"Organization":{"Company":[{"ComapnyAddress":"Address1","CompanyName":"ABCD"},{"ComapnyAddress":"Address2","CompanyName":"PQRS"}]}}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
JSONObject o = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String xml = org.json.XML.toString(o);
```

Comment: Yes its working if i am passing a JsonObject but it's not working if i am passing Json as a String any idea ?

Comment: it requires json object to get the hierarchy...is your problem solved now??

Comment: yup still in the same library org.json they have given the one overload of method which accepts json in string format and while parsing it to the xml its giving &quot.